# how to inflated view set Condition is null or not

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-inflate, android-viewgroup

I want to check infalted view Edittext null or not if it is null then I want to set error below particular Edittext view. I search on google but not found a satisfied answer.

This is my code I write for inflate view.

```
void inflateData(int passenger) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_addTraveller);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    for (int i = 0; i < passenger; i++) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_flight_traveller, null);
        view.setId(i);
        view.addchi
        main_view = view;

        TextView txt_trave = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_traveller);
        final TextView txt_mr = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_mr);
        final TextView txt_ms = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_ms);
        final TextView txt_mrs = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_mrs);

        final TextInputLayout txtInput_firstName = view.findViewById(R.id.txtInput_firstName);
        TextInputLayout txtInput_middleName = view.findViewById(R.id.txtInput_middleName);
        TextInputLayout txtInput_lastName = view.findViewById(R.id.txtInput_lastName);

        final EditText etx_firstName = view.findViewById(R.id.etx_firstName);
        EditText etx_middleName = view.findViewById(R.id.etx_middleName);
        EditText etx_lastName = view.findViewById(R.id.etx_lastName);

        if (Common.INT_ADULT > i) {
            txt_trave.setText("Adult " + (i + 1));
        } else if ((Common.INT_ADULT + Common.INT_CHILD) > i) {
            txt_trave.setText("Child " + ((i + 1) - Common.INT_ADULT));
        } else if ((Common.INT_ADULT + Common.INT_CHILD + Common.INT_INFANTS) > i) {
            txt_trave.setText("Infant " + ((i + 1) - (Common.INT_ADULT + Common.INT_CHILD)));
        }

        txt_mr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonClick(txt_mr, txt_ms, txt_mrs);
            }
        });

        txt_ms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonClick(txt_ms, txt_mr, txt_mrs);
            }
        });

        txt_mrs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonClick(txt_mrs, txt_mr, txt_ms);
            }
        });


        linearLayout.addView(view);
    }
}
```

and this is my view. 
[image]

Comment: null or you want to check if it is empty or not??

Comment: Shivam Oberoi, yes I want to check it's null or not but my confirm button in Activity and above all view is inflated.

Comment: Instead of this, you can use _RecyclerView_

Answer (score 0):

Try to instantiate all of the edit text from inflated view and inside your main activity where the confirm button is. Just trying to answer your concern :)

Comment: good try, but not satisfied with the answer. Thank you for your reply.